# How to call KeBugCheck or KeBugCheckEx in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I want to use the [KeBugCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551948(v=vs.85).aspx) and [KeBugCheckEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551961(v=vs.85).aspx) methods in my C++ application.
But my problem is that I don't know how to call them.
I tried to add `#include <Ntddk.h>` and `#include <Wdm.h>` at the top of my class, but Visual Studio shows me an error that says that it can't find *Ntddk.h* and *Wdm.h*.
So could you tell me how to include them in my program ? 
Thank you

Comment: Read _"Getting started with Windows Driver Kit"_ (you need to download it etc): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeBugCheck` and `KeBugCheckEx` are only available to kernel-mode device drivers. User-mode applications can't call them, because they crash the entire system.

Comment: Though, you _may_ be able to _indirectly_ raise a bug check if the application context has the permission to shut down the system (I mean `SeShutdownPrivilege` active on application token). It's done by importing NTDLL and calling its `NtRaiseHardError` with `ValidResponseOptions` parameter set to `OPTION_SHUTDOWN_SYSTEM` and the remaining parameters as the application needs.

Comment: @Lukasz032 can you link to anything that expands on this further?

Comment: @CardinalSystem http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FError%2FNtRaiseHardError.html